# Looking for "The Jewish rite of circumcision" (1873) by Asher Asher

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, brit-milah

A Google search doesn't come up with any proper results at all. A jstor link and a University of Glasgow biography of Asher Asher didn't offer a link to the entirety of this publication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read and download the book [here](https://archive.org/details/jewishriteofcirc00ashe/page/n3/mode/2up).